# How Would You Go By Bluring a UIVeiw

Tags: ios, objective-c

hi Im having trouble bluring my UIView. I'm able to get te UIView to show a Translucent one and have the user be able to change it but cant figure out how to blur it. I'm pretty sure that I will need the view to use UIVisualEffectView & UIBlurEffect but can't figure out how to get my view to use the instead of setBackgroundColor.

```objectivec
self.diaryPlayerView = [UIView new];
[[self diaryPlayerView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.10 green:0.10 blue:0.10 alpha:[mediaPlayerBackgroundAmountValue doubleValue]]];
[[self diaryPlayerView] setHidden:YES];
[self addSubview:[self diaryPlayerView]];

[[self diaryPlayerView] setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
    [self.diaryPlayerView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topAnchor],
    [self.diaryPlayerView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.leadingAnchor],
    [self.diaryPlayerView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.trailingAnchor],
    [self.diaryPlayerView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:140 + [mediaPlayerOffsetValue doubleValue]],
]];
```

EDIT

I did the following and the view is only translucent and not blurring like expected

```objectivec
self.diaryPlayerView = [UIView new];
self.MediaPlayerblurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleSystemUltraThinMaterialDark];
self.MediaPlayerEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:MediaPlayerblurEffect];    
[[self diaryPlayerView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.10 green:0.10 blue:0.10 alpha:[mediaPlayerBackgroundAmountValue doubleValue]]];
[[self diaryPlayerView] setHidden:YES];
[self addSubview:[self diaryPlayerView]];
[self addSubview:[self MediaPlayerEffectView]];

[[self diaryPlayerView] setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
    [self.diaryPlayerView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topAnchor],
    [self.diaryPlayerView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.leadingAnchor],
    [self.diaryPlayerView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.trailingAnchor],
    [self.diaryPlayerView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:140 + [mediaPlayerOffsetValue doubleValue]],
]];
```

Comment: Try adding `UIVisualEffectVIew` as a subview of `diaryPlayerView`

Comment: And you can use UIVisualEffectViews just as you do UIViews meaning you can addSubviews.